# Editing front-end url on browser

Tags: php

I'm working on a php project but I would like to hide the url on localhost to appear as if it were an aspx project.

this is how I mean

```
localhost/myproject/index.php
```

to

```
localhost/myproject/index.aspx
```

Comment: Please tell me this is for an ASP class. That would make my day.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what ur asking

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Apache, to do this you need to create a .htaccess file in your root web directory and add this line to it:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .aspx
```

Now your webserver will process pages with a .aspx extension as PHP

Comment: Thank you in advance John..But am not sure I know how to do this, how do i create the htaccess file. I'm currently using xampp as my local host.

Comment: Just create a text file and save it with the file name of `.htaccess`. The period in in the front of the name is required. Then add this line to it and save it and you should be done.

Comment: I have tried the above method but this is what am getting

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script. 

And my project can not even show up in the localhost index

Comment: Your server may have specific requirements for this to work. I would contact your host and let them know what you're doing. They'll be able to tell you what you need to tweak to make it work for you.

Comment: Ok John..but am trying to do this on my localhost